# Scala sortBy parameters as sequence

Tags: scala

I have defined a

```
case class User(var firstName: String, var lastName: String, var city: String, var price: Int)
```

and want sort

```
val users = List(
  User("Peter", "Fox", "Berlin", 30),
  User("Otto",  "Schmidt", "Berlin", 20),
  User("Carl",  "Schmidt", "Berlin", 30),
  User("Igor",  "Schmidt", "Berlin", 10),
  User("Hugo",  "Schmidt", "Berlin", 50))
```

I can do this e.g. by

```
val sorted = users.sortBy(p => (p.lastName,p.firstName))
```

Is it possible to give sortBy the sort criteria by a sequence like this?

```
val sortCriteria = Seq(lastname,firstname)
val sorted = test.sortBy(p => sortCriteria)
```

I want to combine the criterias in the sequence by user request with 1 to n arguments without defining all possible combinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a way to compare two `User`s. The logic is: compare on the first criterion, and if it's 1 or -1, that's the result, else if it's 0, compare on the next criterion.

We have a bit a problem since just providing a `Seq[User => Any]`, we can't convince the compiler that `Any` will have a defined ordering. So how about defining a class that will remember how to compare instances without having to remember the type of the field it's comparing on:

```
case class Criterion[T](crit: User => T)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]) {
  def compare(x: User, y: User): Int = ord.compare(crit(x), crit(y))
}
```

Then we just need to implement the sequential comparison:

```
def ord(criteria: Seq[Criterion[_]]) = new Ordering[User] {
  def compare(x: User, y: User) = {
    def loop(crits: Seq[Criterion[_]]): Int = crits match {
      case Seq() => 0
      case c +: cs => c.compare(x, y) match {
        case 0 => loop(cs)
        case i => i
      }
    }
    loop(criteria)
  }
}
```

We can now try this with your data above

```
val cs = Seq(Criterion(_.price), Criterion(_.firstName))
val sorted = users.sorted(ord(cs))

/* results:
sorted: List[User] = List(
  User(Igor,Schmidt,Berlin,10),       Sorted by Price
  User(Otto,Schmidt,Berlin,20), 
  User(Carl,Schmidt,Berlin,30),      
  User(Peter,Fox,Berlin,30),      <-- Peter now after Carl
  User(Hugo,Schmidt,Berlin,50)) */
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `Tuple`, not a `Seq`.

```
  def sortCritera(user: User): Tuple2[String, String] = (user.firstName, user.lastName)
  println(users.sortBy(user => sortCritera(user)));

  def sortCritera2(user: User): Tuple3[String, String, String] = (user.city, user.firstName, user.lastName)
  println(users.sortBy(user => sortCritera(user)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do something like this. Because internally it uses a stable sort (Merge Sort), hence the below solution works:

```
val order = List("lastName","firstName")

def sort(ls:List[User],n:String) = n match {
  case "firstName" => ls.sortBy(p => p.firstName)
  case "lastName" => ls.sortBy(p => p.lastName)
  case "city" => ls.sortBy(p => p.city)
  case "price" => ls.sortBy(p => p.price)
}

order.reverse.foldLeft(users)((all,param) => sort(all,param))
```

Basically in reverse order, you sort by `firstName` first. And then sort by `lastName`.

This gives same result as `users.sortBy(p => (p.lastName,p.firstName))`

Answer (score 0):

[Accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234357/scala-sortby-parameters-as-sequence/18241975#18241975) is good, but we can do even more. We can pass class dynamically as type so Criterion can be used for different classes. Ordering direction in sorting is important so it should be used too.

Sample code of upgraded Criterion class should look like this:

```
case class Criterion[A,T](crit: A => T, ascending:Boolean)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]) {
  def compare(x: A, y: A): Int = {
    val result = ord.compare(crit(x), crit(y))
    if(ascending) result else result * -1 //If descending change result to opposite value
  }
}
```

And then create companion object for Criterion class like this:

```
object Criterion {
  def ord[ A ]( criteria: Seq[ Criterion[ A, _ ] ] ): Ordering[ A ] = ( x: A, y: A ) => {
    def loop( crits: Seq[ Criterion[ A, _ ] ] ): Int = crits match {
      case Seq() => 0
      case c +: cs => c.compare( x, y ) match {
        case 0 => loop( cs )
        case i => i
      }
    }
    loop( criteria )
  }
}
```

Sorting looks like this:

```
val users = List(
  User("Peter", "Fox", "Berlin", 30),
  User("Otto",  "Schmidt", "Berlin", 20),
  User("Carl",  "Schmidt", "Berlin", 30),
  User("Igor",  "Schmidt", "Berlin", 10),
  User("Hugo",  "Schmidt", "Berlin", 50))

val crits = Seq(
  Criterion[ User, String ]( _.name, true ),
  Criterion[ User, Int]( _.price, false )
)

val sorted = users.sorted( Criterion.ord[ User ]( crits ) )
```